# Element not interactable: element has zero size

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium and still learning. Following along with some older videos and I've ran into a issue where bing.com has a three dot drop menu while the video does not. The script is suppose to go link by link, click and capture the url, go back and move to the next link. However since after the first link everything is under a three dot drop menu, it seems that chrome cant click that element.

```
package WorkingWithLinks;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TC6GetLinkNameAndUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\phaak\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Eclipse Training\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://bing.com");
    
        //count number of link
     
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        //if links are displayed
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
            if (links.get(i).isDisplayed()) {
                //if displayed, link are captured and clicked
                String name = links.get(i).getText();
                links.get(i).click();
            
                //next page url is captured and printed 
                String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                System.out.println(name + "  " + url);
        
                //goes back to previous page
                driver.navigate().back();

                links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error im getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: element not interactable: element has zero size

Comment: I wouldn't use the click at all... just grab the href attribute. ex: links.get(i).getAttribute("href"); (also redefining the links array while you are iterating/looping based on it seems dangerous...)

Comment: @pcalkins sry i should have been more clear, im new to coding in general so im pretty slow on this but can u clarify what the href should be?

Comment: You question is not clear and in the bing home page I could not find tag name with a

Comment: well I don't see any click on a "..." link... I only see this code clicking the links, then getting the current URL and then going back.  But you won't need to do that if all you need it to get the links.  Just use .getAttribute() to get the href (url) of the link.

Comment: got it now, thank you went with a much simpler code -  i hope this is what you were referring to                             
                        for(WebElement link:links) {
   System.out.println(link.getText()+" - "+link.getAttribute("href"));